# How can we get login user in ir.action.act.window in odoo v10?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

We are getting login user in **self.env.user**, but i want to access login user in **ir.action.act.window**.

```xml
    <record id="act_mail_messages_form_ept_closed" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Closed</field>
        <field name="res_model">mail.message</field>
        <field name="domain">[('model','=','res.partner'),('res_id','!=',False),('user.company_id','=',company_id)]</field>         
        <field name="context">{'readonly_by_pass': True,'check_domain':True}</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_message_search"/>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
```

My requirement is I want to filter data without creating record rule, because of if we create record rule of mail.message then system will very slow because for every record system will check record rule.

I want to filter company wise messages using domain in mail.message.

In mail.message i have company_id field (Custom field) and i want to filter data when action is calling.

Is there any alternative solution available to filter message without creating record rule  or is there any way from that we can access login user in **ir.action.act.window** ?

Comment: how about *search_read()* method ? we can also filter record from there.

Comment: Have you tried using `('user.company_id', '=', user.company_id.id)` in your domain? I'm not sure if the domain evaluation allows the use of `user`.

Answer (score 1):

if you need only the id of user for you domain: use `uid`

If you want to filter a records with a complex domain that cannot be don with action then you should use `ir.actions.server` :

XML:

```xml
<record id="action_mail_closed" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Closed</field>
                 <!-- here the name of the module containing mail_message model-->
    <field name="model_id" ref="module_name.mail_message"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">action = model.open_closed()</field>
    <field eval="True" name="condition"/>
</record>
```

Python:

```py
@api.model
def open_closed(self):
    # here you can filter you records as you want
    records = self.env... search(...)
    search_view_id = self.env.ref('module_name.view_message_search')
    return {
        'name': _('Closed'),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'res_model': 'mail.message',
        'search_view_id': search_view_id.id,
        'target': 'current',
        'context': {'readonly_by_pass': True,'check_domain':True},
        # and here show only your records make sure it's not empty
        'domain' : [('id', 'in', records.ids)]
        }
```

Comment: should work there is an example in CRM module : check action id : `action_your_pipeline` in odoo 10.0

Comment: if you need only the id of user you can use `uid`

Comment: yes because it's returned the client side and in client side you can get only uid but you have compnay_id I think just keep in mind that the domain is parsed by client side first and you cannot pass objects

Comment: i don't think you can acces company_id in the ir.actions.act_window because it's not present in the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation where I needed to add domain to show only those results in the tree which are relevant to the logged-in user. This is what worked for me.

**XML**

```
<field name="domain">[('cmp_id','=',uid)]</field>
```

**Python:**

```
cmp_id = fields.Many2one('module.company', related='user_id.company_id')
```

Here module is the custom module which you have made for company, **cmp_id** is a Many2one field which is **related** to the company id through user_id.